# Why does this passage use the imperfect subjunctive?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

I'm reading *Harry Potter y la piedra filosofal* and the following passage has me a tiny bit confused gramatically (I understand the meaning though):

> Quirrell se apartó, con el rostro también quemado, y entonces Harry se dio cuenta: Quirrell no podía tocar su piel sin sufrir un dolor terrible. Su única oportunidad era sujetar a Quirrell, **que sintiera** tanto dolor como para impedir que hiciera el maleficio...

Initially I thought the `que` here was a subordinating conjuction (can you use `que` all by itself like that in Spanish, or would you need something like `para que` instead?), but now I wonder if it's actually introducing a nominal clause, as if the text were `Su única oportunidad era que Quirrell sintiera tanto dolor...`.

Am I on the right track? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of this clause is adjectival.

> que sintiera tanto dolor como para impedir que hiciera el maleficio

is describing Quirell and how he would feel.

> Su única oportunidad era que Quirrell sintiera tanto dolor

The way you rewrite the clause is nominal- that is Quirrel is actively doing the feeling of those things.

Just to clarify **que** and **para que** are both mechanisms for introducing subordinate clauses- whether they be nominal, adjectival, or adverbial  (I would think **Para que** would be most commonly used with nominal clauses, though).

So yes, **que** can be used in this way.